# How reliable is Advanced Installer?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, auto-update, advanced-installer

I am trying to use [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html) as an application installer and auto-updater. Most of the resources is available on Advanced Installer website only.

Have any one used it before? I would like to hear more about bugs / stability issues if there are, especially auto-update feature

Answer (score 8):

Regarding the bug/stability issues, you can see from the [release history](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/version-history.html) the frequency on auto-updater bug fixes (six this year - four in v9.2 and one each in v9.1.1, v9.0.1 and v9.0).

What I've noticed is that occurring issues are promptly solved.

Answer (score 2):

I posted earlier the following:

I have used the free version of Advanced Installer, including its auto-update feature, and I have not experienced any problems with it.

Please note that I was talking about the ability of Advanced Installer MSI scripts to automatically remove older files when upgrading to a newer version of a program. I was not talking about the ability of the application to check for an update automatically. That's probably not in the free feature-set.

Answer (score 1):

I have used advanced Installer It is really good.I would recommend to use it if you are developing a msi setup file for web applications.It is even integrated
with several other tools used for developing such as wix,inno setuo etc

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Advanced Installer, however, just wanted to refer InstallJammer which is a multiplatform installer http://www.installjammer.com/, which I have been using to create application installer and easy to use and configure.

Comment: "InstallJammer is no longer under active development." http://sourceforge.net/projects/installjammer/

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Advanced Installer daily for my work . I can say that their manuals are not helpful enough, especially for people who do not have any experience with those tools
. However if you pay for support , they can help you almost immediately . 
For sure there are some limits about this tools especially if you want your build to be MSI the UI will not respond as well as the exe - but i know they are trying to fix this issue .
If you learn how to use it FOR sure you are going to like it.

The nice part about advanced installer is that they collect analytics (you have to pay for this feature ) and they can show you how many downloads per day , or how many users  chose option 1 rather than option 2.
Or you can send those statistics to your webserver and with POST can manipulate however you want - which is free!

Comment: Windows Installer technology is not something easy, the purpose of our manuals is to teach you into using Advanced Installer, not Windows Installer. That you can find in other materials with a simple search on Google. Also, we do not offer paid support services, all our support queries get an answer, no matter if the user is trying our application or he has a license. The UI limitations are from the MSI (Windows Installer) technology itself, that is why Microsoft is providing an API for enhanced UI.

Comment: Indeed we do have a support collect analytics for your application and you can get a free trial account to see them, but currently we don't have an API that allows you to redirect the data to your own servers or to handle it in any other way, it is all hosted on our servers.